# Are there any good sources that would help me read Lacan's Seminar XVII?

Tags: reference-request, continental-philosophy, postmodernism, psychoanalysis, lacan

I've been interested in psychoanalysis for the past year or so; I've read a little bit of Freud (the introductory lectures, the case study on the Rat Man, Beyond the Pleasure Principle, and about half of Totem and Taboo), have a little understanding about other psychoanalysts from secondary sources (mostly Freud and Beyond), and have read a few of Bruce Fink's books on Lacan.

For a school paper, I wanted to use the four discourses to analyze a book from the Bible, so I wanted to read the seminar where Lacan talks about the four discourses. But, I haven't been able to get through it that easy. Are there any sources that would help with that particular seminar?

Comment: You may already have this dictionary. PDF http://www.davidbardschwarz.com/pdf/evans.pdf

Comment: This looks like an interesting Bibliography if you can get to a good library. https://philpapers.org/sep/lacan/?refresh=1  Sorry I don't know anything about Lacan myself.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some connection to [Aristotle's rhetorical concepts](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/rhetorical_situation/aristotles_rhetorical_situation.html) here, except divided into the four separate discourses, which each have their own dominant term; the field of knowledge or expertise invoked, the one who invokes this knowledge, and who it is that they reason in the place of (perhaps indicated by what is on the right side of the arrow). In this interpretation of the production of the four discourses, S1/$ --> S2/a could be suggestive of the figure of symbolized with 'S1,' expressing an expertise in the dealings of great men from history $(Napoleon, for instance), and reasoning on behalf of the other indicated with S2/a.